# Converting Signed byte array content to decimal with shifting in java

Tags: java, byte, bit-shift

I had a byte array with hex decimal values and I converted that array to decimal values, using the following code

```
byte[] content = message.getFieldValue( "_Decoder Message" ).data();
int[] decContent = new int[ content.length ];
int i = 0;
for ( byte b : content )
   decContent[ i++ ] = b & 0xff;
```

now the array looks like
    decContent = [01 00 05 00 00 00] ;

The first 2 indexes of this array is converted and saved as int value as below

```
 int traceIdlow = decContent[ 0 ] & 0xFF;
 int traceIdhigh = decContent[ 1 ] & 0xFF;
 int TraceId = traceIdlow | ( traceIdhigh << 8 );
```

The last 4 indexes needs to be converted to int as well but I am confused about the shifting whether it should be 8 or 16 .

How can I convert the last 4 indexes to int value so that according to the above example the value becomes

```
00 00 00 05 = 5 in decimal.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Minor (but important) point:  You're not converting to "decimal", you're converting numeric values from byte to integer size.  Then you're you're splitting some of those values that are in bit-packed form into individual integers.  "Decimal" never enters into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int val = decContent[ 2 ] | (decContent[ 3 ] << 8)
  | (decContent[ 4 ] << 16) | (decContent[ 5 ] << 24);
```

Note that an integer is always signed in Java. If the value is unsigned and can get larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you have to put it into a `long` instead.

A little test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[] decContent = new int[] {1,0,5,0,0,0};
    int val = decContent[ 2 ] | (decContent[ 3 ] << 8)
              | (decContent[ 4 ] << 16) | (decContent[ 5 ] << 24);
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

prints the answer 5.

Comment: I was expecting 5 and it sis giving a huge number

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to change the order of the 4 bytes
from: b0 b1 b2 b3
to: b3b2b1b0 in an int variable?

```
  byte[] b = {0x5, 0x44, (byte)0x7f, 0x1};      // convert to 017f4405
  int val = b[3]<<24 |  b[2]<<16 | b[1]<<8 | b[0];
  System.out.println("val="+Integer.toHexString(val)); // val=17f4405
```

Comment: and also convert it to unsigned dec

Comment: Need to add AND of 0xFF to strip sign when byte expanded to int.

Comment: @UmairIqbal - See my note above.  You may PRESENT the data as decimal, but you're not converting it into decimal unless you create a character representation of it.